How to create a user in firebase/auth without automatically authenticating it
I'm creating a registry of people with firebase/firestore and vuejs, but when I'm logged in with one user and register another, the new user is automatically authenticate.
const registerUser = async () => {
  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, password.value);}


I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to create new users in Firebase Authentication from client-side code, without authenticating it?

You have two options, and neither of them are trivial.  1) Initialize a second firebase app and create the user with that app so that the currently signed in user does not first get signed out.  2) create the user using the Firebase Admin SDK on your backend.
